# Two bits in one clock,

Tags: encoding, bit, processor

If we have a pattern for **00,01,10 & 11**, then is it possible to send these patterns by using only **one clock pulse** and a **single bus**?

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about theoretical electronics.

Let's say that you have 4 voltage levels (1v, 2v, 3v and 4v) where 1v represents the quaternary number 0 (the binary number 00), and 4v represents the quaternary number 3 (the binary number 11).

Let's also use a fifth volatage level 0v to represent "nothing". Now we can send pairs of bits (with a 0v break between them to keep things synchronized) using a single pair of wires (one signal wire and one ground/return wire).

Comment: @Aeze If this answer solved your problem you should accept it to close your question and to thank Brendan. Click on the checkmark below this answers score on the left.